# Updating Django's ManytoMany after filter

Tags: django, orm, many-to-many

I was trying to update certain Article's created_by and edited_by which have ManytoMany relation with a user and add another user to it.

I came across 
`MyModel.objects.filter(pk=some_value).update(field1='some value')`

As a way to update with a single query is there a way to update ManytoMany with a single query too?

`Article.objects.filter(Q(created_by__in=[deleted_user_id])| Q(edited_by__in=[deleted_user_id])).update(?)`

What should I replace "?" with?
Assume that I need to add "replacement_user_id" to all those article which the filter returns.

I guess we can do by querying the "through" model maybe.

Comment: What would be the best method to this? if I cannot use .update() method. A for loop for all item in queryset and then .add() is one way that I know. Anything better than this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using update method:

> You can only set non-relation fields and ForeignKey fields using this
>   method.To update a non-relation field, provide the new value as a
>   constant. To update ForeignKey fields, set the new value to be the new
>   model instance you want to point to.

Learn more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

**Update:**

You can add multilple objects like:

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(Q(created_by__in=[deleted_user_id])| Q(edited_by__in=[deleted_user_id]))
created_by_objs = User.objects.filter(...)
edited_by_objs = User.objects.filter(...)

for article in articles:
    #article.created_by.clear() uncomment if needed
    article.created_by.add(*created_by_objs)
    #article.edited_by.clear() uncomment if needed
    article.edited_by.add(*edited_by_objs)
```

Learn more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)

Comment: What would be the best method to this? if I cannot use .update() method. A for loop for all item in queryset and then .add() is one way that I know. Anything better than this?

Comment: @mascot6699 you could do like .add(*[obj1, obj2, obj3]). Learn more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add